# Is there a way to change/add to multiple IDs/Classes within HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, hyperlink

I currently have a website which has multiple different forms, and each form requires Params to be passed between them, I am attempting to have the Params passed at the end of each link, but it currently is not working, here is what I have tried:

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 3</a></li>
<ul/>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("testClassGroup1").href = document
  .getElementsByClassName("testClassGroup1").href + formparams + websiteparams;
```

so I would like the JavaScript lines to affect all 3 links (Group1), so I don't have to write it for each one if possible?, as I will be having multiple links, and quite a few groups in total which will become a large amount of code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Wobbulax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all elements that are found.

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName("testClassGroup1");

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].href += formparams + websiteparams;
}
```

```js
for (const link of links) {
  link.href += formparams + websiteparams;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this, this works in the package i am using and will save me loads of time!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is querySelectorAll
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

```
<ul id="ulId">
  <li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://demonstrationlink.com" class="testClassGroup1">Link 3</a></li>
<ul/>


//Javascript
let ulId = document.getElementById('ulId')
let list = ulId.querySelectorAll('.testClassGroup1')

list.foreach(function(item){
   //action here
});
```

Comment: Hi, This got me half way there but the forms package we are using has some unique aspects, so it was difficult to get the list.forEach to work, But thank you for trying to help me :)